# 2.79 theme for 2.8

Tags: theme

simple question: Did anyone port the default 2.79 theme to 2.8 yet, or at least to a theme that's as similar as possible? Just exporting the old default theme and installing it in 2.8 is mostly ok, but has some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another 2.7x theme based on @Grimm theme + slight tweaks:

https://pastebin.com/ZdV37VA6

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since no one seems to have done this, I needed to do it myself.  :)  And because letting questions rot without an answer isn't appropriate, here's my file:

[BlenderTheme-2.79-for-2.80](https://pastebin.com/yrFqnbJf)